# Feed-Me import csv with Variants

Tags: plugin-feedme, import

I need to set a CSV file format for our Client to be able to import his inventory using Feed-Me plugin.
I've got it to the point where I can't figure how to set the line (cvs) to import variants.
Let's say I've got a variant on color and finish which generate a different SKU number, how would I define my csv line ?

`product name, type, collection, sku, color, finish, sku2, color2, finish, sku3, color3, finish`

as an example.
Your help always appreciated !

Best regards,
Sylvain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to make it to import products and its variants. In this particular case, I put semi-colon as separator and put the appropriate value in config/feed-me.php.

The variant are on the same line and the header shows the variants.

```
title;category;collection;essence;design;class;format;variant/0/l;variant/0/w;variant/0/h;variant/0/price;variant/0/SKU;variant/0/finition;variant/0/side;variant/0/l;variant/0/w;variant/0/h;variant/0/price;variant/0/SKU;variant/0/finition;variant/0/side
door abc;pax;wood;cherry;slab;;;cupboard;12x30;30;12;0.5;22.51;3333;natural;vertical;30;12;0.5;22.51;4444;natural;horizontal
door abc;other;wood;cherry;slab;;;cupboard;12x30;30;12;0.5;22.51;88888;natural;vertical;30;12;0.5;22.51;999999;natural;horizontal
```

NOTE: The values imported need to match one of the value in the case of a "select" field...

Hope this might help someone in the future.

Sylvain